# How do I grab an object from a website using Javascript/Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So let me first explain what I'm trying to achieve even though it's probably not the right way to go about this.

I make discord bots and my goal is to have the bot check with the website before starting/running commands. I *(for obvious reasons)* don't want to put the true/false in the code in the event I need to stop a bot from starting remotely.

I set something up on my *Express* app so that when the specific section of the response matches  the client ID in the array, then grab the piece from the response where it says true or false. Act on it if it doesn't and do nothing if the object is equal to true. I have this part down, however the part that I don't know how to do is access this "object" from the bot.

Does anybody know how to do this?

```js
app.get('/botAuthentication/getToken', (req, res) => {
    if(['7838193829389238'].includes(req.query.authorization)) {

            res.status(200)
            res.send({
                botAuth: true
            })

    } else {
        return res
            .status(401)
            .send( { code: 401, message: "You can't view this page."})
    }
});
```

This code returns the shown object when opened in the browser.

TLDR; How do I grab that object from the website using some sort of library or method?

*I know this might not be the proper way to do this; I am new to web development.*

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: So what's the website and how does the object looks Like?

Comment: @AvivLo If you visit the website in the browser it returns the object.

{"botAuth":true}
I just don't know of any libraries/methods to use that can grab something like that.

Comment: Is it only {"botAuth":true} or is there something more

Comment: Just the object. Nothing else. 
Would node-fetch be an option for something like this?

Comment: Try axios. It's promised-based. Pretty versatile in my opinion.

Comment: @thetechguy61705 That means you need to convert `{"botAuth":true} ` from string json to an object? If yes, you can try `res.json({"botAuth":true})` or in the client, try `JSON.parse(response)`. Hope I understood you question.

Comment: @ThangLe There are two separate programs running on two different machines. One running the website, one running the bot. I need them to talk to each other with that website to see if that value is true

Comment: I am trying Axios right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your bot I suggest you use axios as it is a very easy to use fetch library, but you can use node-fetch, request or pick from many others....

```
const axios = require('axios')

// Somewhere in your bot...
axios.get('https://my-bot-command-and-control.example.com/botAuthentication/getToken', {
  params: : {
    authorization: '7838193829389238'
  }
}).then((response) => {
  if (response.botAuth) {
    // do bot stuff
  }
})
```

A couple of points... As a security perspective, it is imperative that you keep the secret authorization code a secret. That means no putting it in git and outside of your development environment, you must deploy the express server *behind* SSL termnination so the connection between your bot and the API is encrypted. Otherwise you will be transmitting the authorization code in plaintext.